# Remove back button from Android Navigation Bar

Tags: android, launcher, android-navigation-bar

I'm currently writing an application which acts as a home screen/launcher.

When I'm on the home screen, I still have the back button visible in the navbar. Somehow Google manages to hide it in their Pixel launcher and I've read [on GitHub](https://github.com/LawnchairLauncher/Lawnchair/issues/1281#issuecomment-437469780) that it's only possible to hide the back button if the application is a launcher (which is the case for my app).

Unfortunately the Android documentation covers only how to completely hide the navigation bar. I doubt that's the way Google went with their Pixel launcher and I suspect that there is some badly documented way of achieving this.

Comment: You need to be root in order to do it.  It requires access to a hidden API, which also requires system level permissions.  I've done it for a kiosk app where we owned the hardware, but you won't ever get it to work in a play store app.  The reason for such high permissions is that they don't want malware to be able to take away nav buttons and effectively brick a phone.

Comment: Could you please give more info about this "hidden api", since you've been using it?